# Qt Creator 5.3 Need help on understanding the help documentation

Tags: c++

I am new to Qt and have trouble understanding the help document, wish some one can help, much appreciated.

For example:

```
void QList::append(const T & value)
```

I can see the return type is void, and it is a member function of QList.
But what in the brackets really confused me, what does it mean by `const T & value` ?
I tried using a regular QString variable as argument and it worked fine, then why `const`?

Another example is

```
 void QFile::setFileName(const QString & name)
```

The sample code provided in the help document is:

```
QFile file;
file.setFileName("readme.txt");
```

I can not figure out what `QString & name` means, does it have something to do with reference?

Comment: The `const` just means that the method itself can not modify it, so the `QString` will be the same before and after the function call

Comment: Please get a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding C++ instead of a specific problem with code.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious How is "understanding C++" off topic at SO?! I don't think this question is *so* basic, that it should be closed because of that. Templates and const semantics of C++ are rather complex.

Comment: @hyde While const correctness can certainly be a heavy topic, it's not in this case. This is just a request for an explanation of C++ basics. Topics such as the one in this post are covered by books and tutorials which are readily available. However, giving it and you the benefit of the doubt I have voted to reopen.

Comment: The thing is that I have trouble define my question clearly due to lack of knowledge in C++ basics terms. Thank you all for the patience, I know where to start now.

Answer (score 3):

First of all `Qt` is a [framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework), `Qt Creator` is an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). I understand you are a beginner and these things should look confusing but I recommend taking your time and starting learning them step by step.

What you are really confused of is [C++ templates](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/), not `Qt`.

`T` is a generic type and can be specified with the diamond operator(`<>`) like this: `QList<int> integerList;`. Now if you execute `integerList.append(42)` the `T` out there will be interpreted as `int`. If the variable type passed to append function is different than the type specified in `QList<int> integerList;` you will get an error.

The second problem you have is you don't understand [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29).

I recommend reading [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and then continue on. Or at least [a decent language tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/)...

Lastly, this is a forum where people post problems on the code they are working on or issues they have with the code they have already written. You won't find anybody starting to teach you a programming language, that's why you got so many minuses. Here I recommend the [stackoverflow help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: *If the variable type passed to [...] you will get an error.* Only if conversion is not possible. You can, for example, pass a `char` to `QList<int>::append(int)` just like you can do with regular functions taking an `int`.

Comment: Yes, but that's a particular case called implicit conversion. If you start telling him about all the exceptions from the rule you'll confuse him even more. He doesn't know the basics so I pointed out the problems as simple as I could and recommended books/tutorials for him to read.

Comment: Good point about simplicity.

Comment: About "you won't find anybody starting to teach you a programming language", that's a rather blurry line. For example, SO is full of highly voted questions about C++11 asking people to explain details of basic concepts. Of course "new features of C++11" is rather more interesting that "features of C++98", but they're still same type of question.

Comment: By "you won't find anybody starting to teach you a programming language" i referred to the fact that nobody will teach you a programming language from A to Z. Asking for more explanations about C++11 features or some exceptions to the rule is not learning a programming language.